# JAX-RS (Jersey): String from JSON request body still escaped

Tags: jersey, glassfish, jax-rs

This is driving me crazy. I'm working on a REST endpoint in JAX-RS (Glassfish / Jersey). I have a method that's supposed to receive a String, store it and return it. The entire endpoint should consume and produce JSON. But every time I post a String to the method, it's handed to me in escaped form. E.g. if I post:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/myresource", {
  method: "post",
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  body: JSON.stringify("test\ntest"),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
```

and the resource is:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource {

    @POST
    public String set(@NotNull String value){
        // store it
        return storedValue;
    }
}
```

then what is stored, and return to the client, is:

```
"test\ntest"
```

If, however, I wrap the String in an object:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/myresource", {
  method: "post",
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  body: JSON.stringify({value: "test\ntest"}),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
```

with resource

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Wrapper {
        public String value;
    }

    @POST
    public String set(@NotNull Wrapper wrapper) {
        String value = wrapper.value;
        // store it
        return storedValue;
    }
}
```

then the value that's stored and returned to the client is

```
test
test
```

Am I missing something?

```
Glassfish 4.1.1
 - jersey 2.10.4-0
 - json 1.0-0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a feature: when passing Strings, [Jackson assumes you're doing the encoding/decoding yourself](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/342).

I'll leave this here for future generations.

Answer (score 0):

In order to post raw String as JSON using JAX-RS, you can use "@JsonRawValue" provided by fasterxml.jackson

```
Class ResponseObject {

@JsonRawValue
String jsonString;
...
}
```

Whenever you send the response object, unescaped json is sent without slashes.