# Jersey + Jackson - escaping body json string literal

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I have a problem with a simple Jaxrs (jersey) endpoint:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/test")
public String doSomething(String s) {
...
}
```

Whenever I use postman to test it with a simple payload such as `"test_string"`, Jackson escapes leading and trailing double quotes. I then end up with `"\"test_string\""` in java.

As far as I know, the `"test_string"` is valid as a json string literal. If I just send `test_string` (no double quote), it works fine. However, my clients send well-formed Json strings ("test_string")

How can I tell jackson to accept my literals ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAX-RS (Jersey): String from JSON request body still escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279605/jax-rs-jersey-string-from-json-request-body-still-escaped)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have two options:

1: create your own wrapper class and put is as parameter

```
public class TestMapper{
@JsonProperty
public String s;
}
```

2: without Jackson:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(s); 
String result=(String) jsonObj.get("test_string");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have not configured Jersey to auto map the request using Jackson and I dont see you using `ObjectMapper` to parse JSON in the code you provided. The request is recieved as a String and Jersey escapes the quotations to make it a valid Java String. To avoid this, use `ObjectMapper` to parse the string as a `String.class`.